# How to get properties from anonymous type in VB.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, linq, anonymous-types

I am trying to figure out how to get at an anonymous typed object's properties, when that anonymous type isn't created in the current function.

Specifically, I am binding an ASP.NET ListView to LINQ resultset, then trying to process each item in the ItemDataBound event.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Class MyPageClass

    Private Sub Bind()
        Dim items As ItemData = FetchItemData()

        Dim groups = From s In items Group s By Key = s.GroupId Into Group _
                Select GroupID = Key, GroupData = Group

        ' This works fine:
        Dim groupId As Integer = groups(0).GroupID

        lvGroups.DataSource = groups
        lvGroups.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub lvGroups_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvGroups.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            Dim item As ListViewDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
            Dim groupData = item.DataItem  ' This is the anonymous type {GroupId, GroupData}

            ' Next Line Doesn't Work 
            ' Error: Option Strict disallows late binding
            Dim groupId As Integer = groupData.GroupId

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

What do I need to do in lvGroups_ItemDataBound() to get at the item.DataItem.GroupId?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do the select, either create a class to select as (select new MyClass With { prop assignments here }) so that MyClass is an actual physical class that you can return.  Or, you can use the DataBinder class as in:

```
DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(item.DataItem, "GroupId", null);
```

I believe I used that to get a value, which uses reflection to inspect the underlying type.

Comment: That worked.  You GetPropertyValue returns a string, and I know I put an Integer in there, so here's my new code:

Comment: Dim currentGroupId As Integer = Integer.Parse(DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(item.DataItem, "GroupId", Nothing))

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is almost nothing you can do here.  The usefulness of anonymous types is limited to the function in which they are created.  Once you pass them out of the function you lose all of the strongly typed goodness of there properties.  The best solution here is to create a very small struct which encapsulates these properties and uses that instead.

Other options include

- Use latebinding.  This is VB after all
- Use an unsafe casting type inference trick to make it strongly typed again.

I only mentioned the casting trick because it's a valid solution.  However it's even less safe that late binding and given a choice between the two I would choose late binding.

Comment: @NoRefunds,  why?  Everything I listed is a valid solution which will unblock the user and solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is an exampe of getting item of anonymous type from Linq to xml and then sending its properties via email. The linq item is being passed to sendmail function as anonymous type and it investingates its properties via reflection:

```
Public Function ProcessFile(ByRef i_fullFilename As String) As String

    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    Try

        Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(i_fullFilename)

        Dim message = From q In xDoc.Descendants _
                      Where q.Name.LocalName = "ContinuousMessage" _
                      Select q

        Dim nsName As String = message.FirstOrDefault.Name.NamespaceName

        Dim ns As XNamespace = nsName

        Dim messageCollection = From msg In xDoc.Descendants(ns + "ContinuousMessage") _
                                Select customOfficeNumber = msg.Element(ns + "customOfficeNumber").Value, _
                                unitCode = msg.Element(ns + "unitCode").Value, _
                                leadingFileNumber = msg.Element(ns + "leadingFileNumber").Value, _
                                messageType = msg.Element(ns + "messageType").Value, _
                                note = msg.Element(ns + "note").Value, _
                                sendingOrPrintingDate = CType(msg.Element(ns + "sendingOrPrintingDate").Value, Date)

        Dim commonNsName As String = "http://com.com/some/common.xsd"
        Dim commonNs As XNamespace = commonNsName

        Dim tgpiCollection = From item In xDoc.Descendants(ns + "TPGIdentifier") _
                             Select fileNumber = item.Element(commonNs + "fileNumber").Value, _
                            numeral = item.Element(commonNs + "numeral").Value, _
                            fillingNumber = item.Element(commonNs + "FillingNumber").Value

        For Each item In messageCollection
            SendMail(item, "Info")
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        result &= ex.Message
    End Try

    Return result

End Function


Private Sub SendMail(ByRef i_item, ByVal i_errorDescriptionString)

    Dim email As New MailMessage
    email.From = New MailAddress("SuperPuperAutomaticCustomsProcessing@net.net")
    email.To.Add(New MailAddress("net@net.net"))
    email.Subject = "New message from customs received 5115"

    Dim name As String = String.Empty
    Dim value As String = String.Empty
    Dim body As String = String.Empty
    Dim nextLine As String = String.Empty

    Dim propertiesInfo As PropertyInfo() = i_item.GetType().GetProperties()
    For Each prop As PropertyInfo In propertiesInfo

        name = prop.Name
        value = prop.GetValue(i_item, Nothing)
        nextLine = String.Format("   {0}:  {1} {2}", name, value, vbCrLf)
        body = body & nextLine

    Next

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(i_errorDescriptionString) Then
        nextLine = String.Format("   Error Description:  {1} {2}", name, i_errorDescriptionString, vbCrLf)
        body = body & nextLine
    End If

    email.Body = body


    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
    smtp.Host = "smtp.local"
    smtp.Send(email)

End Sub
```